# Is there a Visual Studio Test Project template for NUnit?

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, project-template

Is there an official Visual Studio test project template for NUnit? If not, what might one look like?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no official one. Just start a class library project and import the nUnit assemblies to it.

There are plenty of template how to articles around though - [here](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/vb_internet/aspnet/article.php/c6963) is one.

We can use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnitTemplatesforVisualStudio) official Template for Unit Testing as well.

Comment: FYI: The link above is dead. I think this is the link you may be referring to? https://www.codeguru.com/dotnet/creating-an-nunit-project-template-for-net-part-1/

Answer (score 7):

Somebody on Github made a template: https://github.com/orangutanboy/NUnitTestFixtureTemplate

Answer (score 0):

When creating a MVC application you have the option for creating a unit test project. Does not give examples but provides a framework.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official template for NUnit exists in visual studio.you have to explaicitly download it. But it has general unit test framework.

you need to download  Nunit framework using either  nuget package.
**Select Tool menu -> Library package manager ->manage nuget package for solution**
or
**Select Tool menu -> Library package manager ->package manager for console.**
Add the reference in existing unit test project and remove the existing unit test namespace from it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have created a NUnit Visual Studio project template for the .Net framework, [**here**](https://github.com/nhab/NUnit-Test-VS-Template-.Net-Framework/tree/master).

You can Add The NUnit Nuget package reference for the Newer versions of .Net.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022 Professional project template is available as you can see in image below.

[image]